# Is this the best way to design a mongodb schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm fairly new to programming, and am now at the stage where I am working on projects before starting to apply for jobs. I’m working on an express project and wanted some advice on my schema design, just in case I’m going about things in a horrible way.

The premise of the project is a desk booking app. A business administrator can create an account to register a company and add multiple offices if needed. Employees can also register as employees of a company using the unique company code and passcode, and then book desks in different offices.

This is the schema I have designed, I’ve modelled the data in this way as I want to be able to access the data in different ways e.g. an employee viewing all bookings they have made, as well as an employer viewing all bookings made in an office.

Any feedback would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

NB: When building the project I will have each schema in a different file, and I know I haven't required all the dependencies I will need. The purpose of this question is purely on best practices for mongoose schema design.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const CompanySchema = new Schema({
    companyName: String,
    companyLogo: String,
    uniqueCompanyCode: String,
    companyPasscode: String,
    companyAdmin: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ],
    offices: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Office'
        }
    ],
})

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    bookings: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Booking'
        }
    ]
})

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const OfficeSchema = new Schema({
    officeAddress:{
        streetAddress: String,
        town: String,
        county: String,
        postcode: String
    },
    floorPlan: String,
    desks: [
        {
            deskNumber: Number,
            bookings:{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Booking'
            }
        }
    ]
})

const bookingSchema = new Schema({
    bookedFrom: Date,
    bookedTo: Date,
    bookedBy: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
})
```

Comment: See designing MongoDB NoSQL data at [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/). One of the first steps is to identify the data entities, their attributes and the relationships. Then the kind of operations that will be performed on the data. These are the initial and important stages of the data design process.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using the architecture of Node.js, MongoDB with mongoose, you’ll create these schemas at the beginning of every project so it’s best to get familiar with them.

This is how we create a schema in mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let productSchema = new Schema({
 name: {
  type:String,
  required:true
},
price: {
  type:Number,
  required:true
},
isAvailable: {
  type:Boolean
 }
});

const productModel = mongoose.model("product", productSchema);

module.exports = productModel;
```

The first parameter of the mongoose.model is the name of the collection that will contain the documents. The second parameter is the schema. Now, we need is to export productModel so they can be used elsewhere.

```
 const productModel = mongoose.model("product", productSchema);
```

This productModel is ready to be imported and used to create data following our schema in the product collection. This is a common development pattern when using Node.js and MongoDB. An ODM-like mongoose makes managing your data more intuitive.